# Texture atlas to texture array via PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER

Tags: webgl, webgl2, texture-atlas

I have two questions:

First, is there any more direct, sane way to go from a texture atlas image to a texture array in WebGL than what I'm doing below? I've not tried this, but doing it entirely in WebGL seems possible, though four-times the work and I still have to make two round trips to the GPU to do it.

And am I right that because *buffer data* for `texImage3D()` must come from `PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER`, this data must come directly from the CPU side? I.e. There is no way to copy from one block of GPU memory to a `PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER` without copying it to the CPU first. I'm pretty sure the answer to this is a hard "no".

In case my questions themselves are *stupid* (and they may be), my ultimate goal here is simply to convert a texture atlas PNG to a texture array. From what I've tried, the fastest way to do this by far is via `PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER`, rather than extracting each sub-image and sending them in one at a time, which for large atlases is extremely slow.

This is basically how I'm currently getting my pixel data.

```
const imageToBinary = async (image: HTMLImageElement) => {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;

    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);

    return imageData.data;
};
```

So, I'm creating an HTMLImageElement object, which contains the uncompressed pixel data I want, but has no methods to get at it directly. Then I'm creating a 2D context version containing the same pixel data a second time. Then I'm repopulating the GPU with the same pixel data a third time. Seems bonkers to me, but I don't see a way around it.

Comment: The data for `texImage3D` [doesn't need](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL2RenderingContext/texImage3D) to come from a pixel unpack buffer.

Comment: I know. The advantage of it is that if you have a texture atlas that you want to break down to a texture atlas, you only need to upload the entire image once using a PIXEL_UNPCK_BUFFER and sample it over and over for each array entry. Based on what I've tried, doing it any other way with a large atlas is unacceptably slow.